# Does orientdb have import tools like neo4j's neo4j-import?

Tags: orientdb

I know orientdb etl, but it's too slow. 
In my test, could load 8~10k records per second. 
There is a offline import tool "neo4j-import" in neo4j. On the same server, neo4j-import could be over 200k/s

Answer (score 2):

OrientDB provides you a tool called Teleporter that synchronizes a RDBMS to OrientDB database. Teleporter is fully compatible with several RDBMS that have a JDBC driver: it has been successfully tested Teleporter with Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, PostgreSQL and HyperSQL. Teleporter manages all the necessary type conversions between the different DBMSs and imports all your data as Graph in OrientDB. This feature is available both for the OrientDB Enterprise Edition and the OrientDB Community Edition. But beware: in community edition you can migrate your source relational database but you cannot enjoy the synchronize feature, only available in the enterprise edition.
You can find more info here: https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/teleporter/Teleporter-Home.html

In case you should import a Neo4j graph database into OrientDB you can use Neo4j to OrientDB Importer.
You can find more info here: https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/neo4j-to-orientdb-importer/

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: what i need is a offline import tool(extremely fast) in orientdb just like "neo4j-import" in neo4j.   I'm not importing data from neo4j to orientdb.

Comment: did you try the ETL with plocal: storage? Speed of ETL depends a lot on the kind of operations you are doing. The better way is, IMHO, to import vertexes and then create edges after, to avoid too much lookup during the ETL process.